# Проверка подписи файла x509

Tags: c#

Пишу курсовую работу до сдачи которой примерно 13 часов. В шарпе ни в зуб ногой, но пишу на php, python, так что с ООП знаком, все нормально. Суть следующая: "Получить и проверить цифровую подпись файла, в качестве пары ключей используется самоподписанный x509. Сертификат поставляется в виде файла, расположенному по пути, указанному пользователем программы."

Так вот. Идея вроде проста: получаем сертификат из файла

```
try
{
    X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("c:\\r\\1.dll");
    Console.Write("certificate info :"+ theSigner.GetCertHashString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("No digital signature ");
}
```

Далее по идее

```
if ( theSigner.Verify() )
{
    Console.Write("Certificate is verified");
}
else 
{
    Console.Write("Cert can't be verified");
}
```

и все... вроде бы. Но вот же загвоздка: по заданию нам говорят, что нужно указать местоположение сертификата, которым подписывали проверяемый файл. Зачем?

Comment: "по заданию нам говорят, что нужно указать местоположение сертификата" Указать где?

Comment: @Alexey "...Сертификат поставляется в виде файла, расположенному по пути, указанному пользователем программы..."

Comment: @Alexey речь идет о том, что пользователь программы выбирает файл, который он проверяет, выбирает сертификат, которым был подписан проверяемый файл и происходит проверка, как я понял. Возможно, я просто не понимаю чего то?

Comment: Ну я понял это точно так же. Может под  "нужно указать местоположение сертификата, которым подписывали проверяемый файл" подразумевается поиск и нахождение сертификата которым реально подписали файл т.к. указанный пользователем сертификат может быть другим... Но, учитывая, что это курсовая такой вариант маловероятен...

Comment: @Alexey я не очень хорошо понимаю работу x509 verify, поэтому предполагаю:

Когда вызовется Verify() на сертификат, полученный из подписанного файла, верификация будет смотреть на наличие такого-же сертификата в хранилище данной машины. Если она его там найдет, то он говорит что все нормально, если нет, то не нормально. Так вот, есть предположение, что сертификат в чистом виде пользователем предоставляется чтобы он был до верификации добавлен в хранилище.

Прав ли я?

Comment: Вот, тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Написано следующее: CreateFromSignedFile(String) Создает сертификат X.509v3 из заданного подписанного файла. Т.е. тут  X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("c:\\r\\1.dll"); вы генерите сертификат из из подписанного файла. Вот что такое .Verify() мне не совсем понятно... Метод расширения? у X509Certificate класса такого метода нет...

Comment: Полагаю, что в данном методе вы берёте файл сертификата  который указал пользователь и сравниваете их хеши. И, под "что нужно указать местоположение сертификата, которым подписывали проверяемый файл" в таком случае возможно подразумевается, что в выводе в консоль нужно добавить местоположение/имя файла сертификата с которым производилось сравнение

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы проверить подпись файла нужно несколько вещей.

1. Понять, что именно подписано в файле, к примеру для PE-файлов это кусок файла без нескольких заголовков, до самой подписи, закодированной в формате SignedData PKCS#7 (ASN.1), сертификаты, которыми подписаны многие файлы лежат внутри этой структуры, не надо искать их содержимое, достаточно определить степень доверия им.
2. Иметь эту самую "подпись" файла - это массив байтов некоторой величины, которая тоже находится внутри вышеупомянутой структуры подписи.
3. Иметь x509 сертификат, которым подписан файл.

Сертификат получить просто (F# 4):

```
let cert = certFilePath |> File.ReadAllBytes |> X509Certificate2
```

Дальше нужно взять публичный ключ этого сертификата и привести его к `RSACryptoServiceProvider` или `DSACryptoServiceProvider`:

```
match cert.PublicKey.Key with
| :? RSACryptoServiceProvider as rsa -> ...
| :? DSACryptoServiceProvider as dsa -> ...
| x -> raise NotSupportedException(sprintf "This algorithm is not supported: %O" (x.GetType())
```

В случае с RSA-ключом вам нужно знать, каким алгоритмом было выполнено хэширование, функция `VerifyData` написана MS-ом очень плохо, второй параметр у неё `object`. По опыту туда нужно передать смапленный `DigestAlgorithm` который есть в `ASN.1` структуре подписи, в виде строки. При этом часто `OID` в виде строки передать нельзя, приходится передавать название алгоритма, в которые мапятся `OIDы`. Примеры: `"MD5"`, `"SHA1"`, `"SHA256"`, `"SHA384"`, `"SHA512"`. Частный случай: `1.2.840.113549.1.1.11` мапится в `"SHA256"`, кроме того ещё несколько вариантов `OID` мапится в этот алгоритм.

О том, как можно разбирать PKCS#7 структуру `SignedData` - можно писать отдельный пост. О всех недостатках библиотеки `BouncyCastle` в том числе.